# Trivial example using spaCy Matcher not working

Tags: spacy

I'm trying to get the following simple example using the spaCy Matcher working:

```
import en_core_web_sm
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern1 = [{'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'ORTH': '.'}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'ORTH': '.'}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'ORTH': '.'}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}]
pattern2 = [{'LIKE_NUM': True}, {'ORTH': '.'}, {'LIKE_NUM': True}, {'ORTH': '.'}, {'LIKE_NUM': True}, {'ORTH': '.'}, {'LIKE_NUM': True}]
pattern3 = [{'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'IS_PUNCT': True}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'IS_PUNCT': True}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'IS_PUNCT': True}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}]

matcher.add('IP', None, pattern1, pattern2, pattern3)

doc = nlp(u'This is an IP address: 192.168.1.1')

matches = matcher(doc)
```

However, none of the patterns are matching and this code returns `[]` for `matches`. The simple "Hello World" example provided in the spaCy sample code works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the `Matcher`, keep in mind that each dictionary in the pattern represents *one individual token*. This also means that the matches it finds depends on how spaCy tokenizes your text. By default, spaCy's English tokenizer will split your example text like this:

```
>>> doc = nlp("This is an IP address: 192.168.1.1")
>>> [t.text for t in doc]
['This', 'is', 'an', 'IP', 'address', ':', '192.168.1.1']
```

`192.168.1.1` stays one token (which, objectively, is probably quite reasonable – an IP address could be considered a word). So the match pattern that expects parts of it to be individual tokens won't match.

In order to change this behaviour, you could [customise the tokenizer](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers) with an additional rule that tells spaCy to split periods between numbers. However, this might also produce other, unintended side effects.

So a better approach in your case would be to work with the token shape, available as the `token.shape_` attribute. The shape is a string representation of the token that describes the individual characters, and whether they contain digits, uppercase/lowercase characters and punctuation. The IP address shape looks like this:

```
>>> ip_address = doc[6]
>>> ip_address.shape_
'ddd.ddd.d.d'
```

You can either just filter your document and check that `token.shape_ == 'ddd.ddd.d.d'`, or use the `'SHAPE'` as a key in your match pattern (for a single token) to find sentences or phrases containing tokens of that shape.

Comment: Thanks for the super-helpful and super-fast response!